# Does Xcode search attributed strings in storyboards?

Tags: xcode, xcode-storyboard

When I do "find all" in Xcode, I expect to get results from every part of the project, including the storyboard. Are attributed strings included in this search?

Answer (score 5):

No. See this example from Xcode 8.3.3.
[image: Xcode storyboard]